# call an activity on java android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclick, oncreate

first of all, i'm a noob at java programing for android.
Now, I have a button in the main layout that suppose to call an activity, now what do I write in the onClick method of the button? and I can't use onCreate in the activity that is being called, so what do I use in there?
thanks

Comment: This is a very trivial task, it takes less effort to google this, than to ask a question here, for which you have already gotten suggestions that it may have already been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the `onClick` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The system will start the activity `Activity` as soon as possible, which will lead to it's `onCreate` method being called.

Answer (score 1):

This will start new activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: `this` points to the Button context, you need to reference application context/activity.

Answer (score 0):

You basically follow this pattern:

```
onClick() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, <TargetIntent>.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Intent` first and pass your current activity instance and nect activity to it. Then call that activity through `startActivity()`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class);

startActivity(i);
```